# set ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL to custom value

Tags: android, contactscontract

I call an intent to add a contact to device like this :

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
                    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,
                            user.getName());
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.IM_HANDLE,
                            user.getID());
                    intent.putExtra(
                            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.IM_PROTOCOL,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_CUSTOM);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.html#PROTOCOL) says:

> public static final String PROTOCOL
>     This column should be populated
>   with one of the defined constants, e.g. PROTOCOL_YAHOO. If the value
>   of this column is PROTOCOL_CUSTOM, the CUSTOM_PROTOCOL should contain
>   the name of the custom protocol. Constant Value: "data5".

When I click to add or edit contact a pop-up dialog appear with empty edittext where I have to select the name of **CUSTOM_PROTOCOL**. According to the docs I cant find the way how to set **CUSTOM_PROTOCOL** value.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem yet? I am struggling with the exact same issue.

Comment: Yes I did. You cannot passed custom protocol via intent. :(

Comment: Thanks for your response. What code did you use to replace the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom protocol this way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, user.getName());

ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA, user.getID());
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_CUSTOM);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL, "your_protocol");
data.add(values);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```